# How EXACTLY does Firefox choose a java version?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, java

I have two version of Java installed:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe   (1.7.0_51)
C:\Java\bin\javaw.exe                            (1.6.0_38)
```

I want Firefox to use the latter (don't ask; shitty work software). I don't want to uninstall Java 7 as I use it for Android development, but I don't care about having it as a browser plugin. No matter what I do it Firefox always finds Java 7, and not Java 6. Here are the things I've tried:

### 1. Disable Java version

In the Java Control Panel (both of them), I did this:

[image: a]

It appears to have no effect. Firefox still finds Java 7. Weirdly only the Java 7 version shows up in the System tab - any idea why?

### 2. Make Java 6 the default plugin.

I opened `c:\Java\bin\javacpl.exe` and checked the Mozilla family checkbox below:

[image: b]

It gives a dialog box *claiming* that browser settings have been changed. But if I just close the control panel and reopen it the checkbox has been automatically unchecked!

So my question is: how exactly does Firefox find and prioritise Java versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems all those settings are ignored and Firefox just uses a setting in the registry. Change the following keys in the obvious way:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins@java.com/JavaPlugin\Path
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins@java.com/JavaPlugin\Version

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins@java.com/JavaPlugin,version=10.51.2\Path
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins@java.com/JavaPlugin,version=10.51.2\Version
```

Note the format for the version numbers is slightly different in each case. Also this is for 32 bit Firefox on 64 bit Windows. The keys may be in other places for 32 bit Windows. Hell maybe the "Default Java for Browsers" checkbox actually works then! Anyway if you can't find these keys try searching for `npjp2.dll` in the registry values or data.

[image: no]
[image: no]